# DataProtectionProvider in the Identity sample project

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, owin

The official Identity 2 sample project has the code below in `UserManager.Create()`

```
public static UserManager Create(IdentityFactoryOptions<UserManager> options, IOwinContext context) {

  //...etc...

  // --- what does this block do? ---
  var dataProtectionProvider = options.DataProtectionProvider;
  if (dataProtectionProvider != null) {
    manager.UserTokenProvider = new DataProtectorTokenProvider<User>(dataProtectionProvider.Create("ASP.NET Identity"));
  }
  // --------------------------------

  //...etc...

}
```

The alpha/beta/RTM Identity documentation is bad or non-existent.

What does this do?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The protection provider in the following line is used as a token provider/generator.

```
manager.UserTokenProvider = new DataProtectorTokenProvider<User>(dataProtectionProvider.Create("ASP.NET Identity"));
```

It is responsible for generating an email confirmation token or a password reset token. If you do not set this line you won't be able to use this features (an appropriate exception will be thrown). An example can be found [here](http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/features-api/account-confirmation-and-password-recovery-with-aspnet-identity).

Its main purpose is to provide an implementation of the [IDataProtector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.owin.security.dataprotection.idataprotector(v=vs.113).aspx) interface (through the *Create* method) which encrypts and decrypts data. An implementation for this interface in the framework is the **DpapiDataProtectionProvider** which should be used when the application is not hosted by ASP.NET. There are several other implementations on the web (for example one which uses the machine key for security purposes). class For more information about the DataProtectorTokenProvider have a look at the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn613292(v=vs.108).aspx).

**UPDATE**

Extensive [Data Protection documentation](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/security/data-protection/introduction.html) is now available.

Comment: MSDN: "Represents a token provider that uses an IDataProtector to generate encrypted tokens based off of the security stamp". Huh? Like I said the official docs are really useless (as of this writing) for Identity API.

Comment: I don't allow external logins, or users to create accounts. I only need to create internal accounts for admins. So can I safely remove this code block?

Comment: In my opinion you can. Why don't you just test it? It was not part of ASP.NET Identity v1 and if you don't use some of the new features it should work.

Comment: Thanks @Horizon_Net for this hint to use the DpapiDataProtectionProvider . I needed that provider in an integration test when the options.DataProtectorTokenProvider was null :-)

Comment: I know this was answered a while ago, but I thought i'd try and ask anyway.  The value that is set there by default: "ASP.NET Identity", does it matter?  In other words, does it has to be this exact value, or this can be absolutely anything.  What I am trying to understand is how is this value used?  Are tokens hashed with this value or this is to identify some internal class to be used or such?

Comment: @Bagzli [The Data Protection documentation](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/security/data-protection/introduction.html) seems to indicate that the "ASP.NET Identity" string serves to categorize or tag the protected data. So, when unprotecting data, you'd need to use the same exact string to get the result I believe. The example code in that section is helpful, but also this Problem Statement: *I need to persist trusted information for later retrieval, but I do not trust the persistence mechanism. (i.e. I need to round-trip trusted data via an untrusted client)*.

Comment: @WayneBloss "so in other words if I were to change the value to ABC it would no longer work?"  Or it would work I just need to use ABC when applying decryption?

Comment: @Bagzli I think that if you have any outstanding tokens (in your database or in say...a cookie or local storage in your customers' browsers...) then changing the purpose-string at this point would make those tokens fail. However, tokens created with the new purpose-string would be able to be decrypted. That's just my understanding based on a *very* quick read of the docs and I plan to do further reading before relying on my current understanding.

Comment: @Bagzli You should probably create another question on stackoverflow.com for this specific concern. If you don't, I may.

Comment: @WayneBloss I'll go ahead and let you have create it as you seem to have more understanding of the issue.  If you don't mind just tag me with a link once you do so I can keep an eye on it.

Comment: I use it with custom user authentication... i'm wonder if it get reseted in startup in `app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);` or it try to catch a reference of user which someone point to (read user before user apply) and it fails.... any thing it is... it is failing :'(